# Concatenating continuation lines

Tags: replace

I have a text file like this:

```
Line text,line text
 next line
 3rd line
Line x
```

where 2nd and 3rd, etc lines begin with a single space.  I need to concatenate all lines prefixed with a space to the previous one without a space, so that the result looks like this:

```
Line text,line text next line 3rd line
Line x
```

The lengths of the lines can vary, and there can be many blocks like this.  Can I re-format the entire file with a single command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace the new lines plus space by a space:

```
:%s/\n\s/ /
```

This is an ex command i.e. a command used in the command line mode. To enter the command line mode, press <kbd>:</kbd>. Then insert the command which does the following:

```
%        Apply the command on all the lines of the buffer
s/       The command to apply. 's' is for substitute
\n\s     The pattern to substitute here it is a new line \n followed by a space \s
/<space> The expression used to replace the pattern (here it is a simple space
/        The command must end with a / because you could add some flags
```

Please see [`:h :s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s)

Answer (score 13):

For every line beginning with a space, join it with the previous one:

```
:g/^ /-j
```

*References*

`:help :global`
`:help pattern`
`:help [range]`
`:help :join`

Comment: I like the global command, your solution is nice!

Answer (score 5):

You can join lines with `J`. In your case:

```
3J
```

Will join your 3 lines.

In the case you want more than 3 lines, you can do as follow:

- enter visual mode
- `/^[^ ]/-1`
- `J`

This will select the desired lines and join them.

The search will look to the next line starting with a non-space character, and move up one line.

If you want to do this without entering visual mode, you can use the `join` command preceded by the desired range:

```
:,/^[^ ]/-1 j
```

Comment: can I do it outside of visual mode?

Comment: You can, look at my edit